# How to call Goodreads API (get info from book title or author) in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

i am a newbie to xamarin forms.

How to call goodreads api (method: book.title) in xamarin forms?

I have followed [this link](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.com/2017/04/xamarinforms-consuming-rest-webserivce.html).
But not getting any output since loader starts to load and continuously loading but not getting any output.

i am actually confused of how to write goodreads response in C# get; set; classes form..
I believe i have done some error in this because i am unable to understand how to write and also how to bind this with .xaml file?

goodreads response consists of many subtags so its difficult to write them in C# (get; set;) classes form.

goodreads response looks like this:

```
<work>
<id type="integer">3634639</id>
<books_count type="integer">347</books_count>
<ratings_count type="integer">719250</ratings_count>
<text_reviews_count type="integer">20915</text_reviews_count>
<original_publication_year type="integer">1965</original_publication_year>
<original_publication_month type="integer">6</original_publication_month>
<original_publication_day type="integer">1</original_publication_day>
<average_rating>4.23</average_rating>
<best_book type="Book">
<id type="integer">44767458</id>
<title>Dune (Dune, #1)</title>
<author>
<id type="integer">58</id>
<name>Frank Herbert</name>
</author>
<image_url>https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1555447414l/44767458._SX98_.jpg</image_url>
<small_image_url>https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1555447414l/44767458._SY75_.jpg</small_image_url>
</best_book>
</work>
<work>
```

i am using this URL to call goodreads api method book.title in xamarin forms.

URL: https://www.goodreads.com/search/index.xml?key=Uxb0zPb86N4STVy2ECWYA&q=Dune

Answer (score 0):

load the results into an `XDocument` and use `LINQ` to query them

```
var client = new WebClient();
var response = client.DownloadString(url);

// load data into an XML doc
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(response);

var titles = (from x in doc.Document.Root.Descendants("title") select x.Value).ToList<string>();
```